# WinAPI C++ set child "window" Edit (input text field) to difrent background color

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to set the background color of the Edit control to, for example, blue (just trying), or what I would like to use more is `LTGRAY_BRUSH`. I have already tried a lot of answers to similar questions, but nothing works.

Code piece I tried:

```cpp
case WM_CTLCOLOREDIT:
    if (LOWORD(wParam) == 11) {
        HDC hdc = (HDC)wParam;
        SetBkColor(hdc, RGB(0,0,255));
        SetDCBrushColor(hdc, RGB(0,0,255));
        return (LRESULT)GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH);
    }
```

Complete code so far:

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cassert>

HWND hWndEdit;
wchar_t buffer[1024];

LRESULT CALLBACK MessageHandler(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (uMsg) {
    case WM_CLOSE:
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
        break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == 10) {
            GetWindowText(hWndEdit, buffer, 1024);
            MessageBox(hWnd, buffer, L"Button gedrückt", MB_OK);
        }
        break;
    case WM_CTLCOLOREDIT:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == 11) {
            HDC hdc = (HDC)wParam;
            SetBkColor(hdc, RGB(0,0,255));
            SetDCBrushColor(hdc, RGB(0,0,255));
            return (LRESULT)GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH);
        }
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    
    HWND hWnd;
    HWND hButton;
    WNDCLASS wc;
    MSG msg;

    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = MessageHandler;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WINLOGO);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"WINAPITest";

    assert(RegisterClass(&wc));

    hWnd = CreateWindow(L"WINAPITest", L"WinAPI Tutorial", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 500, 500, 0, 0, hInstance, 0);
    hButton = CreateWindow(L"button", L"OK", WS_VISIBLE | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON | WS_TABSTOP | WS_CHILD, 100, 100, 200, 50, hWnd, (HMENU)10, hInstance, 0);
    hWndEdit = CreateWindow(L"edit", L"Tastzyklen", WS_TABSTOP | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | WS_VISIBLE, 100, 48, 200, 50, hWnd, (HMENU)11, 0, 0);

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    while (true) {
        BOOL result = GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0);
        if (result > 0) {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
        else {
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Is what I want to do possible? I want the Edit control from the beginning to have a different background color from the main window.

It's hard to find useful resources to learn from about this topic. Primarily, I want the above question answered, but if someone can guide me to a resource that can help me understand all of this better and possible the answer I am given, I would appreciate it.

Why does the Edit control have two backgrounds colors?

[image]

Blue is `SetBkColor` and Grey is `SetDCBruchColor`.

Comment: You seem to assume that `LOWORD(wParam)` would contain the ID of the control. This is not the case, per [the fine manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/wm-ctlcoloredit)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik so how do i check the ID of the control? If i remove the if and only write `return (LRESULT)GetStockObject(LTGRAY_BRUSH);` it changes color but a second control would change color as well.Also is there a different background for text? Because yes the color is different but where the text is it is still white in the control.

Comment: "*so how do i check the ID of the control?*" - the `lParam` of `WM_CTLCOLOREDIT` is the `HWND` of the edit control being colored. Compare that to the child `HWND`s you create, eg: `if (hWndEdit == (HWND)lParam)`. If you really need to check IDs instead, you can use `GetDlgCtrlID()` to get the `HWND`'s ID, eg: `if (GetDlgCtrlID((HWND)lParam) == 11)`. As for the text color, you can use `SetTextColor()` in the same `WM_CTLCOLOREDIT` handler.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks `if (hWndEdit == (HWND)lParam)` worked. Coulde you explain why the edit has two backgrounds colors?  current background `SetBkColor(hdc, RGB(0,0,255));` and current device context (DC) brush color `SetDCBrushColor(hdc, RGB(0,0,255));` I don't understand the difrence and why they exist i only see what happens if i don't use one of them.

Comment: @Hatux I can't really answer that, as I had never heard of `SetDCBrushColor` before today. Can you provide a screenshot of what the Edit control looks like when you set `SetBkColor()` and `SetDCBrushColor()` to different colors?

Comment: @RemyLebeau there should be an screen shot in the post now

Comment: `SetBkColor` is used by `TextOut` and similar, when the text is rendered. The brush you return is used to paint the whole background of the control, before the text is rendered. `SetDCBrushColor` is used to change the color of the stock `DC_BRUSH` that you have returned.